# How to assign Multiple variable based on condition in a single sql statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How to assign the multiple variable based on condition in sql server 2008R2? I am able to do it by accessing the table separately for each variable, but I want to do it in a single statement. Here is the code I written it in a single statement but as CASE expression returns only single value.

```
SELECT 

   @Sun_ST = CASE WHEN (isnull(@Sun_ShiftCode,'') <> '') AND Std.Shift_Code = @Sun_ShiftCode THEN replicate('0',2-len(convert(varchar,Std.Start_Hour))) + convert(varchar,Std.Start_Hour) + replicate('0',2-len(convert(varchar,Std.Start_Minute))) + convert(varchar,Std.Start_Minute) END,

   @Sun_ET = CASE WHEN (isnull(@Sun_ShiftCode,'') <> '') AND Std.Shift_Code = @Sun_ShiftCode THEN replicate('0',2-len(convert(varchar,Std.End_Hour))) + convert(varchar,Std.End_Hour) + replicate('0',2-len(convert(varchar,Std.End_Minute))) + convert(varchar,Std.End_Minute) END,

   @Mon_ST = CASE WHEN (isnull(@Mon_ShiftCode,'') <> '') AND Std.Shift_Code = @Mon_ShiftCode THEN replicate('0',2-len(convert(varchar,Std.Start_Hour))) + convert(varchar,Std.Start_Hour) + replicate('0',2-len(convert(varchar,Std.Start_Minute))) + convert(varchar,Std.Start_Minute)END,

   @Mon_ET = CASE WHEN (isnull(@Mon_ShiftCode,'') <> '') AND Std.Shift_Code = @Mon_ShiftCode THEN replicate('0',2-len(convert(varchar,Std.End_Hour))) + convert(varchar,Std.End_Hour) + replicate('0',2-len(convert(varchar,Std.End_Minute))) + convert(varchar,Std.End_Minute) END,

   @Tue_ST = CASE WHEN (isnull(@Tue_ShiftCode,'') <> '') AND Std.Shift_Code = @Tue_ShiftCode THEN replicate('0',2-len(convert(varchar,Std.Start_Hour))) + convert(varchar,Std.Start_Hour) + replicate('0',2-len(convert(varchar,Std.Start_Minute))) + convert(varchar,Std.Start_Minute) END,

   @Tue_ET = CASE WHEN (isnull(@Tue_ShiftCode,'') <> '') AND Std.Shift_Code = @Tue_ShiftCode THEN replicate('0',2-len(convert(varchar,Std.End_Hour))) + convert(varchar,Std.End_Hour) + replicate('0',2-len(convert(varchar,Std.End_Minute))) + convert(varchar,Std.End_Minute) END,

   @Wed_ST = CASE WHEN (isnull(@Wed_ShiftCode,'') <> '') AND Std.Shift_Code = @Wed_ShiftCode THEN replicate('0',2-len(convert(varchar,Std.Start_Hour))) + convert(varchar,Std.Start_Hour) + replicate('0',2-len(convert(varchar,Std.Start_Minute))) + convert(varchar,Std.Start_Minute) END,

   @Wed_ET = CASE WHEN (isnull(@Wed_ShiftCode,'') <> '') AND Std.Shift_Code = @Wed_ShiftCode THEN replicate('0',2-len(convert(varchar,Std.End_Hour))) + convert(varchar,Std.End_Hour) + replicate('0',2-len(convert(varchar,Std.End_Minute))) + convert(varchar,Std.End_Minute)END,

   @Thu_ST = CASE WHEN (isnull(@Thu_ShiftCode,'') <> '') AND Std.Shift_Code = @Thu_ShiftCode THEN replicate('0',2-len(convert(varchar,Std.Start_Hour))) + convert(varchar,Std.Start_Hour) + replicate('0',2-len(convert(varchar,Std.Start_Minute))) + convert(varchar,Std.Start_Minute) END,

   @Thu_ET = CASE WHEN (isnull(@Thu_ShiftCode,'') <> '') AND Std.Shift_Code = @Thu_ShiftCode THEN replicate('0',2-len(convert(varchar,Std.End_Hour))) + convert(varchar,Std.End_Hour) + replicate('0',2-len(convert(varchar,Std.End_Minute))) + convert(varchar,Std.End_Minute) END,

   @Fri_ST = CASE WHEN (isnull(@Fri_ShiftCode,'') <> '') AND Std.Shift_Code = @Fri_ShiftCode THEN replicate('0',2-len(convert(varchar,Std.Start_Hour))) + convert(varchar,Std.Start_Hour) + replicate('0',2-len(convert(varchar,Std.Start_Minute))) + convert(varchar,Std.Start_Minute) END,

   @Fri_ET = CASE WHEN (isnull(@Fri_ShiftCode,'') <> '') AND Std.Shift_Code = @Fri_ShiftCode THEN replicate('0',2-len(convert(varchar,Std.End_Hour))) + convert(varchar,Std.End_Hour) + replicate('0',2-len(convert(varchar,Std.End_Minute))) + convert(varchar,Std.End_Minute) END,

   @Sat_ST = CASE WHEN (isnull(@Sat_ShiftCode,'') <> '') AND Std.Shift_Code = @Sat_ShiftCode THEN replicate('0',2-len(convert(varchar,Std.Start_Hour))) + convert(varchar,Std.Start_Hour) + replicate('0',2-len(convert(varchar,Std.Start_Minute))) + convert(varchar,Std.Start_Minute) END,

   @Sat_ET = CASE WHEN (isnull(@Sat_ShiftCode,'') <> '') AND Std.Shift_Code = @Sat_ShiftCode THEN replicate('0',2-len(convert(varchar,Std.End_Hour))) + convert(varchar,Std.End_Hour) + replicate('0',2-len(convert(varchar,Std.End_Minute))) + convert(varchar,Std.End_Minute) END
FROM dbo.Table Std
WHERE Std.Country_Code = @Country_Code
```

Comment: It is unclear what do you want to achieve. In your query you are assigning multiple variables. Please provide expected result

Comment: You can only made one assignment per case (one expression per WHEN-statement). You will have to move your conditions(s) to the WHERE statement.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
declare @Sun_ShiftCode int=1
declare @Mon_ShiftCode int=2
declare @Tue_ShiftCode int=3
declare @Wed_ShiftCode int=4
declare @Thu_ShiftCode int=5
declare @Fri_ShiftCode int=6
declare @Sat_ShiftCode int=7


declare @Sun_ST varchar(10);
declare @Sun_ET varchar(10);
declare @Mon_ST varchar(10);
declare @Mon_ET varchar(10);
declare @Tue_ST varchar(10);
declare @Tue_ET varchar(10);
declare @Wed_ST varchar(10);
declare @Wed_ET varchar(10);
declare @Thu_ST varchar(10);
declare @Thu_ET varchar(10);
declare @Fri_ST varchar(10);
declare @Fri_ET varchar(10);
declare @Sat_ST varchar(10);
declare @Sat_ET varchar(10);

declare @country_code int=1

;with Tab as
(
select
*
from 
(values
(1,'8','0','17','0',1)
,(2,'8','5','16','50',1)
,(3,'8','10','16','40',1)
,(4,'8','15','16','30',1)
,(5,'8','20','16','20',1)
,(6,'8','25','16','10',1)
,(7,'8','30','16','0',1)
)a(Shift_Code,Start_Hour,Start_Minute,End_Hour,End_Minute,Country_Code)
)
select
 @Sun_ST=max(case when Shift_Code=@Sun_ShiftCode then  right('00'+Std.Start_Hour,2)+right('00'+Std.Start_Minute,2) else '' end)
,@Sun_ET=max(case when Shift_Code=@Sun_ShiftCode then  right('00'+Std.End_Hour,2)  +right('00'+Std.End_Minute,2)     else '' end)
,@Mon_ST=max(case when Shift_Code=@Mon_ShiftCode then  right('00'+Std.Start_Hour,2)+right('00'+Std.Start_Minute,2) else '' end)
,@Mon_ET=max(case when Shift_Code=@Mon_ShiftCode then  right('00'+Std.End_Hour,2)  +right('00'+Std.End_Minute,2)     else '' end)
,@Tue_ST=max(case when Shift_Code=@Tue_ShiftCode then  right('00'+Std.Start_Hour,2)+right('00'+Std.Start_Minute,2) else '' end)
,@Tue_ET=max(case when Shift_Code=@Tue_ShiftCode then  right('00'+Std.End_Hour,2)  +right('00'+Std.End_Minute,2)     else '' end)
,@Wed_ST=max(case when Shift_Code=@Wed_ShiftCode then  right('00'+Std.Start_Hour,2)+right('00'+Std.Start_Minute,2) else '' end)
,@Wed_ET=max(case when Shift_Code=@Wed_ShiftCode then  right('00'+Std.End_Hour,2)  +right('00'+Std.End_Minute,2)     else '' end)
,@Thu_ST=max(case when Shift_Code=@Thu_ShiftCode then  right('00'+Std.Start_Hour,2)+right('00'+Std.Start_Minute,2) else '' end)
,@Thu_ET=max(case when Shift_Code=@Thu_ShiftCode then  right('00'+Std.End_Hour,2)  +right('00'+Std.End_Minute,2)     else '' end)
,@Fri_ST=max(case when Shift_Code=@Fri_ShiftCode then  right('00'+Std.Start_Hour,2)+right('00'+Std.Start_Minute,2) else '' end)
,@Fri_ET=max(case when Shift_Code=@Fri_ShiftCode then  right('00'+Std.End_Hour,2)  +right('00'+Std.End_Minute,2)     else '' end)
,@Sat_ST=max(case when Shift_Code=@Sat_ShiftCode then  right('00'+Std.Start_Hour,2)+right('00'+Std.Start_Minute,2) else '' end)
,@Sat_ET=max(case when Shift_Code=@Sat_ShiftCode then  right('00'+Std.End_Hour,2)  +right('00'+Std.End_Minute,2)     else '' end)
from tab Std
WHERE Std.Country_Code = @Country_Code
and std.Shift_Code is not null


select @Sun_ST Sun_ST
, @Sun_ET Sun_ET
, @Mon_ST Mon_ST
, @Mon_ET Mon_ET
, @Tue_ST Tue_ST
, @Tue_ET Tue_ET
, @Wed_ST Wed_ST
, @Wed_ET Wed_ET
, @Thu_ST Thu_ST
, @Thu_ET Thu_ET
, @Fri_ST Fri_ST
, @Fri_ET Fri_ET
, @Sat_ST Sat_ST
, @Sat_ET Sat_ET
```